# Get current user information and add to email action in workflow?

Tags: workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013. I hace created a workflow on a list. In this workflow I have created a "send email" action. I would like to add current user information like:

```
Full name
Phonenumber
Department
etc
```

How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consume SharePoint 2013 REST API from a SharePoint Designer Workflow to retrieve user details from `User Information List`

### Solution description

Steps:

1)Create and initialize variable for storing REST endpoint Url 
[image]

> Note: to retrieve user details (Email, Department and etc.) the
>   following REST query is used:
>
> ```
> /_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=(ID eq <UserId>)
> ```

2)Utilize `Call HTTP Web Service` action to call SharePoint REST service
[image]

Follow [this article](http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) that describes how to use Call HTTP Web Service action.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with SharePoint Designer Workflows, you can select Data Source as "User Profiles" and in the Field from Source, you have many options like selecting Department, Account Name, First Name, Last Name etc.

[image: Workflow Data Source]

Reference:

[User Profile Data in SharePoint Designer Workflows](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/04/user-profile-data-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/)

PS: This is for SharePoint 2010, but hope it will be same for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: But I need to implement the mapping. You can see it in your printscreen: "Find the List Item". How can I map the current user?

Comment: Workflow Context: Initiator should give you current user

Comment: Confirmed it is working in SP2013 too.