# SPD Workflow Response Code: NotAcceptable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow

I am using the approach posted here by Vadim Gremyachev: [Get current user information and add to email action in workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97971/get-current-user-information-and-add-to-email-action-in-workflow)

here the REST-URL: `/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=(ID eq <UserId>)`

But the response code returns

> NotAcceptable

I have the needed permissons on the list and site and also I am not using system account.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing this SO post, you probably need Accept header. Like: "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose". http://stackoverflow.com/a/14252326/1934559

Comment: I specified the requestHeader dictonary but forgot to set it in the web service call! *facepalm*, thx Akhoy!

Comment: Should I add it as an answer so you can mark it?

Comment: yes, you can but maybe write also to check the web service call action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing this SO post: [406-Not Acceptable Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252326/1934559), you probably need `Accept` header.

`"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"`.

You need to add this in your web service call action.